# pycharm не видит стандартные модули

Tags: pycharm

Имеется:

- Win10
- PyCharm 5.0.4 pro
- python 3.5.1

Проблема: после установки новой версии python и удаления старой (3.4) PyCharm отказывается видеть стандартные модули python.

Вот список замеченных проблем в редакторе:

- Не получается импортировать модули. Например `sys` и `os`. Их подчеркивает красным.
- `print()` не работает - подчеркивает красным.
- Нет автодополнения

При этом команда `run` или `python console`, из того же PyCharm, запускаются, как надо, импортируется, что надо, все ок. А вот в редакторе проблема.

Интерпретатор указан, а куда еще смотреть не знаю, нужна помощь.

Comment: Посмотрите, у Вас %PATH% и %PYTHONPATH% какие указаны?

Comment: F:\Python35\Lib;F:\Python35\DLLs;F:\Python35\Lib\tkl; - pythonpath, F:\Python35\Scripts\;F:\Python35\ - path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была где-то в [конфиге](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-python-skeletons.html), просто переименовал (что бы не удалять на всякий случай) папку *config*, и перезапустил пайчарм. После стартовых настроек все заработало как надо.

Comment: Добрый день. Где находится папка *config*?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего пайчарм тут не причем, просто не настроен интерпретатор.
Перейдите в ***settings->Project:Имя_вашего_проекта->Project Interpreter.***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажмите на шестеренку, а затем '*add local*'. Подождите пока загрузится дерево и выберите python нужной версии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убедитесь, что в настройках установлен новый интерпретатор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Interpreter указан, локальный - проблема, удаленный - ок

Comment: У меня несколько раз была подобная проблема. Решалась пересозданием интерпретатора.