# PyCharm выделяет импорт серым

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, библиотеки, python-import

Здраствуйте. Ситуация такая. Pycharm не видит стандартные библиотеки (в данном случае - библиотеку random, на первой картинке). Версия Community Edition 2018.3.3 x64. Пробовал советы из вопроса ([pycharm не видит стандартные модули](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495094/pycharm-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)), но удаление/переименование папки config (которая на второй картинке, возможно, просто удалил не ту) результатов не дало, а нажав на шестерёнку, add local я не нашёл (на третьей картинке, на четвёртой - что при переходе через шестерёнку). Также почитал этот совет ([PyCharm и стандартные модули](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922231/pycharm-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)), но у меня, вроде бы, уже стоит venv.

P.S. Я совсем новичок, буду благодарен, если ответите как можно понятнее. Спасибо :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наведите мышь на import и прочтите сообщение об ошибке:

> Unused import statement

Подразумевается что `random` не используется нигде в данном скрипте. Попробуйте использовать модуль ниже - серая подсветка должна пропасть.

Когда PyCharm не видит модуль, то подсвечивает импорт красным. Сообщение в данном случае будет "no module named ...".