# Python + PyCharm выделяет импорт серым

Tags: python, pycharm, библиотеки

Хочу написать код по отправке сообщений.
Взял инструкцию с видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7NlFZNoFq4
Если смотреть куске на 1:45, то у него import smtplib подсвечивается (т.е. активно), а у меня серого цвета. Искал инфу по ошибке "Unused import statement 'import smtplib'", но не понял как ее устранить.
Т.е. почему на видео сразу активно, а у меня ошибка.[image: Вид редактора]
Соответственно... не работает.

P.S. Не судите строго, только учусь...

Comment: А `smtplib` у вас установлен? И кстати, у вас `pass` не хватает в функции `main`.

Comment: Серым выделены импорты, которые не используется. "Unused import statement 'import smtplib'"" - это не ошибка, это предупреждение. Чтобы импорт не подсвечивался серым, нужно написать код, который этот импортируемый модуль использует.

Comment: @Глеб это стандартный модуль: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Comment: В видео тоже сказано что это стандартный модуль. Я отдельно не ставил.

Comment: У меня, конечно в меню Settings -> Python Interpreter кроме pip ничего нет :)

Comment: Собственно, аналогичный вопрос: [PyCharm выделяет импорт серым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/945992/1365)

Comment: @АлексейБ прочитайте второй комментарий (мой). Это не ошибка и вообще фактически не проблема.

Comment: И еще, может подскажете... есть ли люди, которые за некоторую плату могу сопровождать на начальном этапе? Т.е. я не говорю про учебу, т.к. в инете есть информация, а я сам неплохо знаю VB, но мне жалко времени на подобные разборы по ошибкам настройки... либо нужна помощь в поиске информации...

Comment: @АлексейБ есть, такие люди называются менторами. Это не на фриланс явно, и тут сайт тоже направлен на решение конкретных проблем. Но можно поискать в интернете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PyCharm выделяет импорт серым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/945992/pycharm-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bc)